# Tell which ViewController pushed the DetailViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a DetailViewController, which is pushed/entered from RootViewController1 OR RootViewController2 through storyboard segues when Cell is selected.

The DetailViewController have a button with an `IBAction`. Can I program the action like:

If parent ViewController is RootViewController2, return. Else, perform Action.
Something like this:

```
-(IBAction)actionButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (parentViewController == RootViewController2) {
        return;
    }

    //Else this is done:
    textLabel.text = @"Test";
}
```

But I'm not sure how to make it work, an example of this would be great. Let me know if you need more info!

EDIT:

Code now looks like this:

```
#import "RootViewController2.h"

...

-(IBAction)actionButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[RootViewController2 class]]) {
        return;
    }

    //Else this is done:
    textLabel.text = @"Test";
}
```

But action is still performed from both views. Further suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @Matt mentioned, the view controllers are stored in an array. You can access the navigation controller array like this:

```
[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastobject ]
[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];

You can also get a reference to the parent view controller like this:
self.parentViewController
self.presentingViewController
```

regardless of how you obtain a reference to the parent, you still need to have a way to compare that reference.  You could use introspection like this  if ([object isKindOfClass:MyClass class]).  But somehow in that approach (using the view controller arrays) you need an object reference to each parent objects.  Its a tricky way to go.

Another possibly easier approach is to set a property value in the view controller before you segue to it in -(void)prepareForSegue .... block.  Something like this:

```
 MyClass *myClass = segue.destinationViewController;
 myClass.myLogicProperty = @"mommy";
```

and in the other segue from the other view controller

```
MyClass *myClass = segue.destinationViewController;
 myClass.myLogicProperty = @"daddy";
```

Now, when your button is pushed, you can just for against those values and then do the correct thing.

```
if ([self.myLogicProperty isEqualTo:@"daddy"]) {
   //take action
}
else if ([self.myLogicProperty isEqualTo:@"mommy"]) {
   //take action
}
else {
//do something if no match
}
```

Not knowing your specific needs, I'd recommend the latter and advise against trying to use the viewcontrollers array.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The view controllers pushed onto a `UINavigationController` form a stack (a linear sequence). You can fetch this stack as the `UINavigationController's` `viewControllers` array. (You can refer to the `UINavigationController` itself as a pushed view controller's `navigationController`.) Since this detail controller is at the top of the stack (the end of the stack), the one you want to know about is the previous one - the next-to-last item of the array.

Comment: I know it can be done, yes, but I need a code example how to check if previous ViewController's name is "ViewController2", like I'm trying to do with this line: if (parentViewController == RootViewController2) {

Comment: `isKindOfClass:` should be the method you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "RootViewController2.h"

...

-(IBAction)actionButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
#define CurrentParentViewController [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] count] - 2]
if([CurrentParentViewController isKindOfClass:[RootViewController2 class]]) {
    return;
}

//Else this is done:
textLabel.text = @"Test";
}
```